# Determine if drop coordinates is over another element using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the [vue-draggable-resizable](https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable) component that will give the x,y offset coordinates as to where my element was dropped on the page (that all works great).  However, I would like to know if there's a way to the determine if the drop coordinates overlaps another element.  I basically have pages stacked down the page and would like to know which page the element was dropped over so I can update the page number that the element belongs to.

So, my question is, how can I determine if a given x,y coordinates is overlapping another element?

Comment: You need to know x,y,w,h of every element and then loop true elements and for each check if overlap exists.. If you draw 2 elements  on paper with x,y,w,h you maybe get a better understanding

Comment: Yeah, I knew I could just use a bunch of math and loops to figure it out but I was hoping there would be an easier way that was "built-in".

Comment: You mean like... [drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop)? All you need to do is: when a drag event starts, until it finishes, you turn all the pages (and the overall container) into drop targes and give their children `pointer-events: none`, so you greatly simplify the dropping procedure. Using this you only need to listen to drop events on page elements, not on any of their child components. That's the basics, but it's far from easy.

Comment: And, to make it clear: it has *nothing* to do with Vue. The fact you're doing it in Vue is completely irrelevant. It would be the same in React, Angular, vanilla Javascript or jQuery. Vue, in principle, is quite DOM friendly and DOM compatible. I don't understand why people using it feel the need to ask: *"How is it done in Vue?"* without researching how it's done in DOM, like the wheel needs to be reinvented. In more than 95% of cases in Vue it's done exactly as in native DOM. I'd even go as far as say that's Vue's strongest *"superpower"*.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The problem is that I don't know what I don't know.  I was trying to give as much context to my particular situation as possible so someone doesn't have to come back later and say "well, jeez - why didn't you mention you were using Vue in the first place???"  If Vue is "irrelevant" then you can still answer the question even though I mentioned it.  Thank god for amazing people like tony19 who answers questions with great examples in the context of the question but I wish you luck on your crusade. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use those drop coordinates with [`document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint). The key is to disable [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on `<vue-draggable-resizable>`'s [dragging](https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable#classnamedragging) element so that `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)` can grab the element underneath.

```
// template
<vue-draggable-resizable @dragstop="onDragStop">

// script
methods: {
  onDragStop(x, y) {
    /* For example's sake, this element lookup is simplified in that
       only considers the top-left corner given by `(x,y)`, but
       you might want to evalute additional coordinates e.g., to meet
       a minimum threshold before overlap is verified. */
    const el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    console.log(el);
  }
}

// style
.dragging {
  pointer-events: none; /* ignore for document.elementFromPoint() */
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7j6n5rkkp?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FPage.vue)

Comment: Thank you so much for this and I'm definitely getting closer now.  My actual code is a little more complex than your working example so some of that complexity may be messing it up but I articulated my issue in a new question here if you want to take a crack at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928835/document-elementfrompointx-y-isnt-reporting-correct-child-elements