# document.elementFromPoint(x, y) isn't reporting correct child elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, drag-and-drop

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841278/2109012), I should be able to get the element that an element "drop" occurred over.  However, it's reporting really odd and random results which always seems to be parent elements instead of the actual child element the dragged element is dropped on.

[Here's the FULL CODE EXAMPLE on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l4qwk09n2q) with the pertinent snippets shown below...

```
<div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <drag :transfer-data="{ type: 'textbox', width: 330, height: 50 }" class="draggable-item"
        >Textbox
        <div slot="image" class="drag-image"><div class="field-container" style="width: 330px;height: 50px;">Texbox</div></div></drag
      >
    </div>
    <div id="pages-container" @click.self="deselectAll();">
      <b-alert show variant="info" class="text-center">Drag controls from the left sidebar to the pages below.</b-alert>
      <drop
        class="page-container"
        v-for="(p, index) in pages"
        @drop="onDrop"
        @click.self="deselectAll();"
        :data-page-number="p.pageNumber"
        :key="p.pageNumber + '_page_' + index"
        :style="{ width: p.width + 'px', height: p.height + 'px' }"
      >
        <img src="https://www.kirupa.com/flash/images/single_column_text.png" width="100%" height="100%" :data-page-number="p.pageNumber" @click.self="deselectAll();" />
        <div style="position: absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:white;opacity:0" :data-page-number="p.pageNumber" @click.self="deselectAll();"></div>

        <vue-draggable-resizable
          :id="f.id"
          :style="{ 'z-index': '1044 !important' }"
          :class="{ 'field-container grabbable': true, selected: f.isSelected }"
          v-for="(f, f_index) in getPageFields(fields, p.pageNumber)"
          :key="f.id"
          :min-width="20"
          :min-height="20"
          :x="f.left"
          :y="f.top"
          :w="f.width"
          :h="f.height"
          :parent="false"
          :z-index="f.isSelected ? '1045 !important' : '1044 !important'"
          :prevent-deactivation="true"
          :active.sync="f.isSelected"
          @resizestop="onResizeStop"
          @dragstop="onDragStop"
          @activated="onActivated(f.id);"
          @clicked="onActivated(f.id);"
          >id: {{ f.id }} <br />
          page: {{ p.pageNumber }} fieldIndex: {{ f_index }} selected: {{ f.isSelected }}</vue-draggable-resizable
        >
      </drop>
    </div>
</div>
```

The pertinent JavaScript is shown here (the page number alert test is always `undefined`)...

```
onDragStop(x, y) {
  //...
  const el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  alert("Dropped onto page number: " + el.dataset.pageNumber);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that [DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) takes the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/viewport) coordinates and the coordinates available on `onDragStop()` are relative to the _start_ of the area you're dropping the object to. Even though I tried for a bit, I have no previous experience with Vue and therefore couldn't find a solution but essentially, if you're planning to use the `elementFromPoint()` method you'll need a way to find the viewport coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joao pointed out, `document.elementFromPoint()` requires viewport coordinates, but `VueDraggableResizable` provides offset coordinates (based on its configured lock aspect ratio and bounds) relative to the initial drop-element. You could still get the viewport coordinates by grabbing them from the draggable item itself.

*Steps:*

1. Add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to `<vue-draggable-resizable>` (which will create an array of references to the draggable), and update the `dragstop`-handler to also take an index that we'll use with the applicable `ref` in the next step:

   ```
   // template
   <vue-draggable-resizable
       v-for="(f, f_index) in ..."
       ref="draggable" 
       @dragstop="(x,y) => onDragStop(x,y,f_index)" 
       >

   // script
   onDragStop(x, y, index) { ... }
   ```
2. In the `dragstop`-handler, disable `pointer-events` on the referenced draggable [`$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el) (corresponding to the index from the previous step) so that `document.elementFromPoint()` can grab the element underneath the draggable's viewport coordinates, which we'll get with [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

   ```
   onDragStop(x, y, index) {
     const draggable = this.$refs.draggable[index].$el;
     draggable.style.pointerEvents = 'none'

     const { left: dragX, top: dragY } = draggable.getBoundingClientRect();
     const targetElem = document.elementFromPoint(dragX, dragY);

     draggable.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'

     ...
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3r285zw2p?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FEditor.vue)

Comment: I had to `parseInt` the pageNumber before assigning it so the field won't disappear. https://codesandbox.io/s/r5r7q54jrn but it's working perfectly.  I just need to figure out how to find the correct position over the new page now and I'll be good.  Do you think it would be easier to use math subtract the page one height first or should I just the offset of the new container page? Thanks!

Comment: Where I dropped it on the other page.  I have to figure out where it was dropped on page two so I can move it to page two and update the relative coordinates on that page.

Comment: FYI, I've updated the answer with a simpler solution of determining the viewport coordinates. Regarding the drop coordinates on another page: I don't think height should be considered (which would require accounting for borders/margins/paddings, etc). Instead, I would subtract the target element's coords from the draggable's coords. See the updated demo, which contains a `console.log` for `offsetX` and `offsetY`.